# How can I send audio to BOTH headphone jack and HDMI?

Tags: audio

I know how to use `amixer` to send output to either the headphone jack or the HDMI port, but I want to send output to BOTH devices. How can I accomplish this?

I'm using official Wheezy Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi model B+.

Comment: Related (but also not really answered): http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38267/how-to-send-audio-to-both-headphone-jack-and-hdmi-simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware it is not possible to duplicate the audio through both of the HDMI port and the headphone jack at the same time due to the way the audio pins are wired up. This is something that most computers can't do without extra software.